# Ruby On Rails - stock_quote specific date issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, httprequest, stockquotes

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I'm implementing a library called [stock_quote](https://rubygems.org/gems/stock_quote/). Using its [Github Documentation](https://github.com/tyrauber/stock_quote/)

I've been able to succesfully use the library, using different methods in RoR, like:

```
StockQuote::Stock.quote
StockQuote::Stock.stats
StockQuote::Stock.chart
```

But I'm having issues to fetch an specific date. For example, I can fetch the last six months in a daily basis, using:

```
@stock_chart = StockQuote::Stock.chart(params[:id], '6m')
```

But I need to fetch an specific date with this method. In the [iextrading documentation](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#chart/), it says:

> "Specific date : IEX-only data by minute for a specified date in the format YYYYMMDD if available. Currently supporting trailing 30 calendar days''

And the HTTP requested is:

```
/stock/aapl/chart/date/20180620
```

[HTTP request highlighted - for specific date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hCKo.png)

I tried to execute this commend in Ruby On Rails, but I haven't been able to translate the HTTP request into a proper RoR format in order to succesfully fetch the trend data. In the stock_quote documentation there is not also any reference to this specific command.

I appreciate any help with this issue, I've tried around 20+ syntax ways but they didn't work.